# Syncing MySQL cross OS with dropbox

Tags: mysql, synchronization, cross-platform, dropbox

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a MySQL database synced and usable by Mac OS X and Windows using dropbox. The question is "Is it possible to do this?, making a single directory of MySQL at disposal of these 2 OSs". I found something about "MySQL server instance" in this: [SQL Server and MySQL Syncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753582/sql-server-and-mysql-syncing) but I'm not yet come near to understanding it. Is it the solution that I'm looking for? From my understanding so far, it allows a single MySQL server to instantiate 2 of its server 1 for Mac and the other for Windows. These servers will receive Windows and Mac commands separately and allow them to Read/Write/Update it? if so i'll continue to read and try to understand it. Or if anyone has a better and simpler solution do tell me so.

Thanks All.

Comment: Can you just have them replicate?

Comment: Replicate? I don't know what that is. Can it support 2 PCs with different OS database interaction simultaneously? Please illuminate me.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html
when you say "simultaneously" - both replication and any conceivable dropbox type solution will suffer from issues where if both sides update the same record, one will be lost. this is concurrency, a complicated topic.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that dropbox downside. And after I read the link that you provided. I still dont see how to implement it. Can you illustrate where the Master and Slave should be? The requirement is that any update from any PC will be done in the other PC too and the "Cross-Platform" is not a problem anymore right?