# Error when executing Insert Trigger with distributed Querys (OpenQuery)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My MSSQL trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ioTrigger_dbo_vsolv_mst_tproddtchng]
ON [dbo].[vsolv_mst_tproddtchng]
for INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT  OPENQUERY (LINKED,'SELECT proddtchng_product_gid,
    proddtchng_mrp,
    proddtchng_tndpwtax,
    proddtchng_tndpwotax,
    proddtchng_kldpwtax,
    proddtchng_kldpwotax,
    proddtchng_costprice,
    proddtchng_website,
    proddtchng_purpose,
    proddtchng_weight,
    proddtchng_suitable,
    proddtchng_workingrange,
    proddtchng_cutoff,
    proddtchng_timedelay,
    proddtchng_description,
    proddtchng_validfrom,
    proddtchng_validto,
    proddtchng_createby,
    proddtchng_createdate,
    proddtchng_isactive,
    proddtchng_isremoved
from  vsolv_line_tn.vsolv_mst_tproddtchng')
SELECT 
    proddtchng_product_gid,
    proddtchng_mrp,
    proddtchng_tndpwtax,
    proddtchng_tndpwotax,
    proddtchng_kldpwtax,
    proddtchng_kldpwotax,
    proddtchng_costprice,
    proddtchng_website,
    proddtchng_purpose,
    proddtchng_weight,
    proddtchng_suitable,
    proddtchng_workingrange,
    proddtchng_cutoff,
    proddtchng_timedelay,
    proddtchng_description,
    proddtchng_validfrom,
    proddtchng_validto,
    proddtchng_createby,
    proddtchng_createdate,
    proddtchng_isactive,
    proddtchng_isremoved
FROM
    inserted;
END
```

When I am executing the above trigger I am getting the following error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKED" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Optional feature not supported".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ioTrigger_dbo_vsolv_mst_tproddtchng, Line 8
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKED" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

I have created a Linked server to Mysql from Sqlserver2008, I have already configured the DTC and its status is running, automatic, please help me how should I overcome the above error.

Comment: Are you trying to create a trigger on Mysql instance using SQL server ?

Comment: Yes I am using..

Comment: Can you give details of what version of SQL you are using and also Mysql, I assume you are missing ODBC driver in your VM ware where MSSQL is hosted or it could be not upto date. Are you able to execute a select query using `openquery`

Comment: sql server 2008,mysql version 5.7 and i can execute select query using openquery

Comment: can you tell me the correct syntax

Comment: @Thomas Nothing wrong with Syntax i bet. Its connection issues with Linked servers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174043/discussion-between-selvakumar-and-ven).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its your `Distrubution tranasaction` property which breaks while creating procs/triggers into Linked servers, especially with Non-MSSQL connections

1) right click on Linked server

2) Select Properties and enable this- Set Property to False

Run Proc:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SVRLINK',
 @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false
```

[image]

Comment: @selvakumar set it to false instead, Default settings are True

Comment: You might have to restart the instance to get changes effective, i guess both servers are in same infrastructure

Comment: @selvakumar Did you also checked DTC settings : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60858/how-can-i-enable-distributed-transactions-for-a-linked-server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174042/discussion-between-selvakumar-and-ven).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

The SQL-Server is trying to start a distributed transaction for a possible rollback on the linked server (myssql). There are some settings in the linked-server options to enable distributed transactions.

Maybe this will help:
[Distributed Transaction on Linked Server between sql server and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911206/distributed-transaction-on-linked-server-between-sql-server-and-mysql)